# Are these two piecewise functions equivalent or different?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, piecewise-continuity

I got this solution to the inequality $|x - 5| + |x - 4| \ge 3:$

$$|x - 5| + |x - 4| - 3 = 
\begin{cases}
2x - 12& \text{if }x > 5\\
-2 & \text{if }4 \le x \le 5\\
-2x + 6& \text{if }x < 4\\
\end{cases}.
$$

My professor said that it should be $2x - 12 \text{ if } x \ge 5.$

Whose answer is correct? Or are both technically correct?

Comment: Also both of them are technically correct because $2x-12$ gives $-2$ when $x=5$, so it doesn't matter which case you plug it into. Although if you really want to be "correct", the interval that each case covers shouldn't intersect at all, which would indicate that $x>5$ is the more "correct" version. Or, doing $x\ge5$ and $4\le x<5$ also works perfectly fine as well, but looks a bit awkward imo. It's all ultimately up to preference at this point.

Comment: For each piece edge of a continuous piecewise function, it doesn't matter whether it is defined within its left piece or its right piece or even (with redundancy) within both pieces.

Comment: $[4,5]\cup(5,\infty)=[4,5]\cup[5,\infty)=[4,5)\cup[5,\infty)=[4,\infty)$, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image says more than a thousand words :-)

($h$ is the one in bold)
[image: Geogebra drawing]

Comment: That really helped. Thank you